# Will the interpreter optimise for you in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Say that I have two *m*×*n* numpy matrices, `A` and `B`, and an *m*×1 numpy matrix, `v`. I want to evaluate `A @ B.T @ x`.

Evaluating left to right naively, I first have to form an *m*×*m* matrix and then multiply that by the vector `x`. However, any human or smart compiler would evaluate `B.T @ x` first to avoid forming the matrix.

I don't know if this is the case for Python. Will it naively form the matrix evaluating left to right? And if so, can I override this behaviour by using brackets to enforce an order of operations (as in `result = A @ (B.T @ x)`)? Or will Python disregard these brackets upon seeing that the expression is equivalent without them?

Answer (score 3):

> Will it naively form the matrix evaluating left to right?

Yes, the matrix multiply operator is left-associative, like most (but not all) of Python's operators.

The expression `a @ b @ c` is evaluated as `((a @ b) @ c)`, regardless of the size or type of a, b, and c.

The precedence/associativity is determined by the Python interpreter; libraries like NumPy cannot change it.

> Or will Python disregard these brackets upon seeing that the expression is equivalent without them?

No. If you specify an order, Python always follows that order.

> However, any human or smart compiler would evaluate `B.T @ x` first to avoid forming the matrix.

I also experimented with the Numba package. Numba is a library which invokes an optimizing compiler on NumPy-heavy code. I used `fastmath=True`, which allows it to reorder some math operations.

Code:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mult_badorder_nb(A, B, x):
    return (A @ B) @ x
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mult_goodorder_nb(A, B, x):
    return A @ (B @ x)
```

I could not get it to optimize mult_badorder_nb into mult_goodorder_nb. It seems like theoretically it has enough information to do this optimization, but it does not seem to actually do it.

> Is @ associative in all situations?

No, and there are three cases to watch out for.

First, even if (A @ B) @ x is mathematically equivalent to A (B @ x), that does not mean that it is numerically equivalent when done on a computer with finite precision.

For example, here are two matrices that provide different results when multiplied in a different order. I found these through a random search.

```
import numpy as np


A = np.array([[6e-20, 4e-38], [3e-13, 2e-31]])
B = np.linalg.inv(A)
x = np.array([1, 1])
print((A @ B) @ x)
print(A @ (B @ x))
```

Output:

```
[0.99999993 0.29886705]
[ 1.00609092e+00 -1.88414573e+06]
```

Second, @ is not associative when a vector appears in the middle. In other words, if A and B are matrices, and x is a vector, then `(A @ x) @ B` is not equivalent to `A @ (x @ B)`.

Third, if you are working with something other than NumPy arrays, then those types can override @ to do anything, and that might not be associative.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some time tests for the different orderings:

```
In [2]: n,m=1000,2000; A = np.ones((m,n)); B=A.copy(); x=np.ones((m,1))

In [3]: timeit A@B.T@x
832 ms ± 33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: timeit A@(B.T@x)
6.2 ms ± 329 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`einsum` can evaluate alternative evaluation orders:

```
In [5]: timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,kl->il',A,B.T,x, optimize=True)
3.64 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Without `optimize` it evaluates on all three variables at once, so it's not the same as (A@B.T)@x.

```
In [6]: timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,kl->il',A,B.T,x, optimize=False)
29.2 s ± 2.3 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Here's the breakdown of computations for the optimal case:

```
In [7]: print(np.einsum_path('ij,jk,kl->il',A,B.T,x, optimize=True)[1])
  Complete contraction:  ij,jk,kl->il
         Naive scaling:  4
     Optimized scaling:  3
      Naive FLOP count:  1.200e+10
  Optimized FLOP count:  8.000e+06
   Theoretical speedup:  1500.000
  Largest intermediate:  2.000e+03 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3                   kl,jk->lj                                ij,lj->il
   3                   lj,ij->il                                   il->il
```

There's another function that evaluates alternative orders:

```
In [11]: timeit np.linalg.multi_dot((A,B.T,x))
5.96 ms ± 323 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note that these are functions, that do their own evaluations of alternatives.  They don't depend on the interpreter default evaluation order.

Before `@` was added as an operator, we had to write a nested `dot` or `matmul`:

```
In [13]: timeit np.dot(A,np.dot(B.T,x))
6.11 ms ± 279 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```